# javascript input onchange not working

Tags: javascript, input, onchange

why this doesn´t work:

```
inputButton.addEventListener('onchange', jsFunction, false);
```

I change the inputbox and it doesn´t call jsFunction.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try `change` instead of `onchange`

```
inputButton.addEventListener('change', jsFunction, false);
```

Comment: Expanding: We're used to the DOM0 names `onchange`, `onload`, etc. Those were the names of the attributes we used back in the day. The standard DOM2 stuff does away with the "on" part -- so, `change`, `load`, etc. IE's non-standard DOM2 equivalent, `attachEvent`, retains the "on". So the rule is, with `addEventListener`, there's no "on"; with just about everything else, there is.